# Maven in Docker Container. Error: No goals have been specified for this build

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven

I am trying to run a Maven + Spring project in a docker file. As a Maven/Spring newbie, I am not sure why the executable doesn't run in a Docker container. The same build works after I "Clean and Build" in NetBeans IDE and run the java file manually from the IDE.

The error I get when trying to run the same in Docker via `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose run` is:

`No goals have been specified for this build.`

(Full error below, together with `POM`, `dockerfile` and `docker-compose` file)

I have copied the built .jar file (myapp-1.0.jar) into the mymaven folder.

What do I need to do to be able to build and run the executable programme in a Docker container?

Any help here is appreciated :)

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM maven:3.6.3 AS maven

WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN mvn install 

FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk11:alpine-jre

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY --from=maven mymaven/myapp-1.0.jar /opt/app/

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","myapp-1.0.jar"]
```

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
  mymaven:
    image: maven
    depends_on:
      - server1
      - server2
    networks:
      - mynetwork
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>mymaven</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>myapp</name>
    <description>My App</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
             
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Error:**

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time:  0.051 s

[INFO] Finished at: 2022-07-24T10:58:03Z

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The docker-compose file was pointing to the standard Docker image and not the build folder with the dockerfile.

```
  mymaven:
    #image: maven (wrong)
    build: mymaven
    depends_on:
     - server1
     - server2
   networks:
     - mynetwork
```